# How to I make the values in the list box round to two decimal places with this visual basic code

Tags: vb.net

I have written this code in visual basic to solve a basic interest calculation.  The year end balances are shown in the list box and the final total is show in the label.  My problem is that I can not figure out how to round the values in the list box to two decimals.  I have tried various things but with no luck so far so I appreciate any help.

Public Class frmNestEgg
    Private Sub btnPrincipal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        ' Declare and Initialize the variables

```
    Dim Principal As Double = txtPrincipal.Text
    Dim InterestRate As Double = txtInterestRate.Text / 100
    Dim Years As Integer
    Dim FinalTotal As Double
    Dim YrEndAmt As Double

    Years = Integer.Parse(txtYears.Text)

    'Calculate the interest from the principal payment over the years input to create a total value.
    For Years = 1 To Years
        FinalTotal = Principal * Math.Pow((1 + InterestRate), Years)
        YrEndAmt = (FinalTotal - Principal) + Principal
        lstYrEndAmt.Items.Add("Year" & Years & " Balance " & YrEndAmt)
        lblFinalTotal.Visible = True
        lblFinalTotal.Text = FinalTotal.ToString("f1")
    Next


End Sub

Private Sub frmNestEgg_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use

```
Math.Round() 
... & Math.Round(YrEndAmt, 2).ToString()
```

but your code had a flaw: same variable `Years` for looping and end condition

so change:

```
    For Years = 1 To Years
```

to:

```
    Dim Years As Integer, year As Integer

    For year = 1 To Years
```

your entire code would then be:

```
Private Sub btnPrincipal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrincipal.Click
    Dim Principal As Double = txtPrincipal.Text
    Dim InterestRate As Double = txtInterestRate.Text / 100
    Dim Years As Integer, year As Integer
    Dim FinalTotal As Double
    Dim YrEndAmt As Double

    Years = Integer.Parse(txtYears.Text)

    'Calculate the interest from the principal payment over the years input to create a total value.
    For year = 1 To Years
        FinalTotal = Principal * Math.Pow((1 + InterestRate), Years)
        YrEndAmt = (FinalTotal - Principal) + Principal
        lstYrEndAmt.Items.Add("Year" & year & " Balance " & Math.Round(YrEndAmt, 2).ToString())
        lblFinalTotal.Visible = True
        lblFinalTotal.Text = FinalTotal.ToString("f1")
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This is correct and I thank you for your help.  The only problem was with the line

Comment: Thank you for your help this solution worked as long as I use year instead of years after FinalTotal = Principal * Math.Pow(1 + InterestRate), Year). When I made this change the code functioned correctly. When I left it as Years than each year produced the same value which was the FinalTotal value.